# Audio file post processing using Slack API

Tags: python, audio, bots, slack

I'm trying to download audio file from slack post using Slack Webclient API, in the `app_memtion` event handler, I need to retrieve the audio file and process it if it is an audio post:

```
@app.event("app_mention")
def handle_starting_events(body, say, logger):
    if ('files' in body["event"]) and (body["event"]['files'][0]['mimetype'] == 'audio/webm'):
        audiourl = body["event"]['files'][0]['url_private_download']
        print(body["event"]['files'][0])
        response = requests.get(audiourl)
        with open('video.mp4', 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.content)
```

The problem is, the downloaded file is a html file, rather than an expected mp4 file. If I copy paste the link to a web browser, I can download the file and able to play it without any issue.

The variable "body" looks like this:

> {'id': 'F04V96W21NK', 'created': 1679772610, 'timestamp': 1679772610, 'name': 'audio_message.webm', 'title': 'audio_message.webm', 'mimetype': 'audio/webm', 'filetype': 'webm', 'pretty_type': 'WebM', 'user': 'U04PV0SQDEJ', 'user_team': 'T04QR9BEN3A', 'editable': False, 'size': 29313, 'mode': 'hosted', 'is_external': False, 'external_type': '', 'is_public': True, 'public_url_shared': False, 'display_as_bot': False, 'username': '', 'subtype': 'slack_audio', 'transcription': {'status': 'processing'}, 'url_private': 'https://files.slack.com/THEMP4FILE', 'url_private_download': 'https://files.slack.com/THEMP4FILE', 'duration_ms': 1820, 'aac': 'https://files.slack.com/THEMP4FILE', 'audio_wave_samples': [0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 48, 89, 73, 54, 58, 76, 100, 93, 73, 81, 51, 57, 49, 41, 34, 25, 20, 11, 6, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'media_display_type': 'audio', 'permalink': 'https://myworkspace.slack.com/files/U04PV0SQDEJ/F04V96W21NK/audio_message.webm', 'permalink_public': 'https://slack-files.com/MYSLACKSTRING', 'is_starred': False, 'has_rich_preview': False, 'file_access': 'visible'}

I tried all 3 links but nothing worked.

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You must add authentication header in your get request:

```
requests.get(url, headers={'Authorization': 'Bearer %s' % slack_token})
```

The download link will redirect to a login page if no authentication header is used.